# Posting message to MS teams using Incoming Webhook is stopped but returning status code 200

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks

**Requirement**:  Post text message to msteams channel continuously for more than 1 hour from speech to text cognitive api.

**Problem**: It is posting message to channel for some times and all of sudden get stopped to post message to channel. API is returning 200 OK code.

**Current Implementation**: I am using the incoming Webhook in the code below  and sending a small (max one line sentence) to teams channel.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
      using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "webhook endpoint"))
      {

          string msg = "{'text':'" + inputString.Replace("'", "\\'") + "'}";
          request.Content = new StringContent(msg);
          request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
          var res = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

          
      }
  }
```

**Expectation **: Message should be post to teams and visible in channel.

Comment: Could you please confirm whether the message getting sent if you send through postman?

Comment: HI @vikram-MSFT , sure, Message sending through post man and webhook as well but problem is that it got stopped all of sudden after 45 min and api is returning status code ok but message is not going to teams.

Comment: Hello @Upendra If you send a large number of messages in a short period of time, it's possible that you have exceeded the rate limit and their messages are being blocked.
 
 
Can you share your message payload and tenant details along with time of failure?

Comment: @vikram-MSFT sure but how can I share tenant details here?  It is reproducible issues and it is coming in every run.

Comment: if possible we can connect and will demo

Comment: Hello @Upendra can you share your payload and tenant details here ?

Comment: HI @vikram-MSFT ,  Client information , i can't share at public place , I can share payload without key and secrets .  Please do let me know if it works. Issue still reproducible.

Comment: @vikram-MSFT  here is the payload apart from url and keys   {'text':'For that multi domain application of these large models, right If we can crack the code on how to compose.'}

Comment: Hi @Upendra- Could you please verify if now also you are facing same issue or not? Because webhook was not working till yesterday when we were trying but now its sending. Please do verify and let us know. Thanks!

Comment: HI @Prasad-MSFT Yes, it is still coming .

Comment: Hi @Upendra- When we are trying to send now it works fine from our end Please do verify and let us know. Thanks! –

Comment: @vikram-MSFT was there any change ? i am still getting

Comment: we are testing with this sample from our end:
 https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AOfficeDev%2FMicrosoft-Teams-Samples%20incoming%20webhook&type=code

Comment: Please run  it for 1 hour and  it will stop  posting messages on teams.  it is repudiable , could you please me know in which scenarios it is working?